# Search bar box shadow not rendering on iOS?

Tags: ios, css

I've created a search bar intended for use in an iOS application. Below is how it renders in browsers (which is how I want it to):

[image]

This is how it renders on iOS:

[image]

It seems to completely ignore the box shadow. Below is the code used:

```
#search-content input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 75px;
    font-size: .75em;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6em .9em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #bababa, 0 0 0 2px #fff, inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #656565;
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could let me know why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your input field:

```
#search-content input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 75px;
    font-size: .75em;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6em .9em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #bababa, 0 0 0 2px #fff, inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #656565;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Will select as best answer when timer is up! :)